# Not able to display list of string in visualforce email template

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, email-template

I have a controller

```
    public class EmailController
 {
public string AppId{get;set;}

List<App_Child__c> aPRList=[select id,name,status__c from App_Child__c where App__c=:Appid limit 10];

   List<String> status_List=new List<String>();

 public List<String> getStatus() 
{    
     String status;
     for(Approval_Related_Detail__c aPR:aPRList)
    {

        status=aPR.status__c;
        String ab=status;


        status_List.add(ab);

    }

    return status_List;

}
}
```

I am calling it through a component as below

```
 <apex:component Controller="EmailController" access="global">
    <apex:attribute name="AppId" assignTo="{!AppId}" type="String" description="Id of the app"/>
     <apex:repeat value="{!Status}" var="string" id="theRepeat">
   <apex:outputText value="{!string}" id="theValue"/><br/>
   </apex:repeat>
  </apex:component>
```

But I am anot able to see status in my email template .

In email template I am calling component as

```
<c:EmailComponent AppId="{!relatedto.id}"/>
```

I am not sure if I am calling the list of string in my component correctly . Please guide here how can I display list values here  line by line

Comment: You need to iterate the list and render each entry separately in the template. Not sure what else is wrong here, if anything.

Comment: thanks for the reply Phil .But can you please guide me here how to iterate it in the email template

Comment: Being a visualforce template, use [visualforce iteration](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_repeat.htm)..

Comment: I tried using the same in my component part but still wont get the list  
    <apex:repeat value="{!status}" var="string" id="theRepeat">
       <apex:outputText value="{!string}" id="theValue"/><br/>
       </apex:repeat>

Comment: Please update the question to show your updated component template.

Comment: thanks for the update Phil , I have updated the code

Comment: OK, so the remaining issue is that you init the strings before the App ID is set - the query executes too soon. I suggest you update to do the query in the property setter. Have a look at the documentation for how to do this.

Comment: thanks phil its working now . I used the query inside the function and voila its working .

Comment: Great. Please upvote and accept my answer if you are happy to do so.

Answer (score 1):

The query is running before the App ID is set. Move the query into the App ID setter to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

The correct pattern for this is:

```
public class EmailController {
    public appId {get; set;}
    public List<App_Child__c> appChildren {
      get {
        return this.appId != null
          ? [SELECT Status__c FROM App_child__c 
               WHERE App__c = :this.appId]
          : new List<App_Child__c>();
      } private set;
    }
}




 <apex:component Controller="EmailController" access="global">
  <apex:attribute name="AppId" assignTo="{!appId}" type="String" description="Id of the app"/>
   <apex:repeat value="{!appChildren}" var="child" id="theRepeat">
     <apex:outputText value="{!child.Status__c}" id="theValue"/><br/>
   </apex:repeat>
 </apex:component>
```